# Perl XML:LibXML - Dynamic Node

Tags: xml, perl, dynamic, substring

I have been trying to parse an xml with perl. I have a static tree path working properly. However, not every node stays the same between different xml files.

I have this code.

```
foreach my $travelSections ($dom->findnodes('//TRAVELER[@NAME="Final Assembly - 1/16-Traveler"]/...')){
```

The problem is xml to xml this changes "**Final Assembly - 1/16-Traveler**", "**Final Assembly -**", is always at the beginning, and "**-Traveler**" is always at the end. Whatever is in the middle can change. How do I make this more dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument you're passing to `findnodes()` is an XPath expression.  Your example uses a simple equality check (this bit: `@NAME="Final Assembly - 1/16-Traveler`) but there are other options including [XPath functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) that you can use.  For example, the `contains()` function:

```
$dom->findnodes('//TRAVELER[contains(@NAME,"Final Assembly")]/...')
```

You can also use `and` to combine expressions:

```
$dom->findnodes('//TRAVELER[contains(@NAME,"Final Assembly") and contains(@NAME,"traveler")]/...')
```

Here's an example you can play with in the [XPath Sandbox](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/_static/xpath-sandbox/xpath-sandbox.html?q=%2F%2Fperson%5Bcontains(%40name%2C%27Matt%27)%20and%20contains(%40name%2C%27Damon%27)%5D).

It is also possible to us XML::LibXML::XPathContext to register your own functions, written in Perl.  See the [Custom XPath functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod#Custom-XPath-functions) section of the documentation.

Comment: Is there a list of everything that can be called such as contains/findnodes? I've been using this lately. Documentation with examples as well? Also, thank you very much!

https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  I already linked to a list of XPath functions in my answer. XML::LibXML supports the functions from XPath 1.0 (but not 2.0). If you're asking about other Perl methods you can call like `findnodes`, the [docs for XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod) are a good place to look.